# How to fit a glm with sum to zero constraints in R (no reference level)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution

**Question has been rewritten**

I am trying to fit a glm to find out how the rate of events happens (counts/exposure) related to some covariates, with Poisson error.
Counts is the number of events happened and the covariates include age, sex, smoking status, policy class and exposure, where policy class has 6 levels: class 0, class 1, ..., class 5

I was wondering how to:

1. keeping the intercept (if possible? if not please would you explain me why not). [Answered by Affine]
2. making the coefficients of polclass0, ..., polclass5 **sum to 0**, I know somehow I need to use `contr.sum`, but it doesn't work (see below) [An example from [other site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261018/how-to-add-sum-to-zero-constraint-to-glm-in-python), but I couldn't replicated it.
3. I used the +0 in the formula to make the polclass0 "take over" the intercept. However, is it possible to have other categorial variable (e.g. sex, or some categorial variable that takes 3+ values) to have two all coefficients display?

---

Example:

```
    set.seed(123)
    sex <- as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 50, replace=T, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)))
    smoker <- as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 50, replace=T, prob=c(0.3, 0.7)))
    polclass <- as.factor(sample(0:5, 50, replace=T))
    age <- sample(16:80, 50, replace=T)
    count <- rpois(50, 2.5)
    exposure <- rgamma(50, 100)

    glm1 <- glm(count ~ polclass + sex + smoker + age + offset(log(exposure)) + 0 ,
                family=poisson(link='log'), contrasts = list(polclass = contr.sum))

    summary(glm1)


        Call:
        glm(formula = count ~ polclass + sex + smoker + age + offset(log(exposure)) + 
            0, family = poisson(link = "log"), contrasts = list(polclass = contr.sum))

        Deviance Residuals: 
            Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
        -2.3604  -0.5625  -0.1263   0.5246   1.5584  

        Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
        polclass0 -3.719037   0.423105  -8.790   <2e-16 ***
        polclass1 -3.347628   0.328248 -10.198   <2e-16 ***
        polclass2 -3.638992   0.368175  -9.884   <2e-16 ***
        polclass3 -3.833882   0.426819  -8.982   <2e-16 ***
        polclass4 -3.780837   0.399512  -9.464   <2e-16 ***
        polclass5 -3.838007   0.373120 -10.286   <2e-16 ***
        sex1      -0.057738   0.091936  -0.628    0.530    
        smoker1   -0.174328   0.118654  -1.469    0.142    
        age       -0.001846   0.006362  -0.290    0.772    
        ---
        Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

        (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

            Null deviance: 8764.667  on 50  degrees of freedom
        Residual deviance:   40.865  on 41  degrees of freedom
        AIC: 189

        Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

as you can see, the contr.sum doesn't work and I would like to know why and how to do that exactly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot have an intercept and dummy variables for all categories. This would result in perfect collinearity and R would automatically drop one of the categories. "Dummy variable trap" would probably be the most common search term.

Comment: Understood, thank you for the tips and I will look into it. So I take it as, it is not possible to have all variables display: i.e. PolClass as well as Sex (i.e. Female, Male, PolClass0, ... PolClass5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who is interested in the question, I have found an answer.

By setting `contrasts(polclass) <- contr.sum(6, contrasts=TRUE)`, the output coefs should add up to zero, i.e. coefficients of polclass5 = - sum of (polclass0, ..., polclass4).

Although glm only gives the first k-1 coefficients (in our case k is 6) to us, the last one can be determine by those k-1 coefs.

By default, the `polclass1, ..., polclass5` you see in summary is actually corresponding to: `poclass0, ..., polclass4` in the original data matrix

```
set.seed(123)
sex <- as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 50, replace=T, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)))
smoker <- as.factor(sample(c(0,1), 50, replace=T, prob=c(0.3, 0.7)))
polclass <- as.factor(sample(0:5, 50, replace=T))
age <- sample(16:80, 50, replace=T)
count <- rpois(50, 2.5)
exposure <- rgamma(50, 100)


contrasts(polclass) <- contr.sum(6, contrasts=TRUE)
glm2 <- glm(count ~ polclass + sex + smoker + age + offset(log(exposure)) ,
        family=poisson(link='log'))

summary(glm2)

    Call:
    glm(formula = count ~ polclass + sex + smoker + age + offset(log(exposure)), 
        family = poisson(link = "log"))

    Deviance Residuals: 
        Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
    -2.3604  -0.5625  -0.1263   0.5246   1.5584  

    Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
    (Intercept) -3.925130   0.367393 -10.684   <2e-16 ***
    polclass1   -0.025973   0.214758  -0.121   0.9037    
    polclass2    0.345436   0.171635   2.013   0.0442 *  
    polclass3    0.054072   0.216232   0.250   0.8025    
    polclass4   -0.140818   0.232781  -0.605   0.5452    
    polclass5   -0.087774   0.237383  -0.370   0.7116    
    sex1         0.115476   0.183873   0.628   0.5300    
    smoker1      0.348655   0.237309   1.469   0.1418    
    age         -0.001846   0.006362  -0.290   0.7717    
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    (Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

        Null deviance: 49.961  on 49  degrees of freedom
    Residual deviance: 40.865  on 41  degrees of freedom
    AIC: 189

    Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

---

Therefore, we have coefficients

```
    polclass0 = -0.025973
    polclass1 =  0.345436
    polclass2 =  0.054072   
    polclass3 = -0.140818   
    polclass4 = -0.087774 
    polclass5 = -(-0.025973 + 0.345436 + 0.054072 + -0.140818 + -0.087774)
```

Answer (score 2):

In short: The intercept takes on the reference level.  Each Polclass in the output is the incremental gain over the reference level.

If you want to explore the differences between Polclass, you would use `polclass <- relevel(polclass, "1")` and then re-run GLM.  You'll do this for each reference level.

```
                Ref0     Ref1     Ref2     Ref3     Ref4     Ref5
(Intercept) -3.95110 -3.57969 -3.87106 -4.06595 -4.01290 -4.07007
sex1         0.11548  0.11548  0.11548  0.11548  0.11548  0.11548
smoker1      0.34866  0.34866  0.34866  0.34866  0.34866  0.34866

polclass0         NA -0.37141 -0.08004  0.11485  0.06180  0.11897
polclass1    0.37141       NA  0.29136  0.48625  0.43321  0.49038
polclass2    0.08004 -0.29136       NA  0.19489  0.14185  0.19902
polclass3   -0.11485 -0.48625 -0.19489       NA -0.05304  0.00413
polclass4   -0.06180 -0.43321 -0.14185  0.05304       NA  0.05717
polclass5   -0.11897 -0.49038 -0.19902 -0.00413 -0.05717       NA

age         -0.00185 -0.00185 -0.00185 -0.00185 -0.00185 -0.00185
```

I re-ran the model with the different reference levels and then compiled the coefficients in the table above.  All other coefficients (except the intercept) stay the same but each polclass changes at the different reference levels.  This happens since the intercept takes into account the reference level average.

If you want to examine the impact of the different polclasses, you'd have to look at each model and make some sort of inference based on your understanding of the data.