# calculating std error

Tags: standard-error

In this topic, you explain how you get to to point estimate of the last class.

[How to fit a glm with sum to zero constraints in R (no reference level)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162381/how-to-fit-a-glm-with-sum-to-zero-constraints-in-r-no-reference-level/163148#163148?newreg=ef1f23fe46cd4bad88c8c7ed4c5186c0)

I wonder, how do you calculate the st error, because I have this problem and want to know something about the significance of the last level of my category.

Thank you very much in advance, 
Kind regards,

ST

Comment: Please edit your question to include whatever information is necessary to understand and answer it. People usually don't want to navigate elsewhere & sift through stuff so that they can answer your question for you.